# Defining data inside code section in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, sections, opcode, fasm

Below is a small piece of code from a program I am working on.

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable
start:
    jmp     skip_data ; no need to execute data
    my_data     db      1,2,3,4,5
    my_data_end:

skip_data:
    mov     ecx,my_data_end - my_data
    mov     esi,my_data
```

I am working on fasm. Here I am intentionally defining the data inside my code section to check something. I assembled it and saw the executable using hex editor. My code section is starting from offset `200`. The data `my_data` was stored from offset `202` which is expected as `jmp skip_data` takes 2 bytes in its encoding but later when I saw the opcode for `mov esi,my_data`, it was `BE 02 10 40 00`. Now `BE` corresponds to `mov esi,` but I am unable to understand the next 4 bytes here. I was expecting that in place of `my_data`, I will have `202` as it is the starting offset address of my data in code section but here I am having something else. I am not sure what these 4 encoded bytes mean here.

My second doubt is about storing data in code section. What impact will it have if I store my data in code section instead of data section. Of course the data in this case will not be writable but will it have any other difference apart from this ? What do code and data section flags signify in general ?

Comment: Your `.text` section does not start at absolute address zero. Looks like it's linked at `0x401000`. If you used a hex editor that likely gave you a file offset, not a virtual memory address that the cpu will use.

Comment: Not sure how you determined that. As I said, I am guessing you used a hex editor that just gives you a file offset which is irrelevant. That is just how the PE file is laid out.

Comment: Okay now I am more confused. From what i know, the file offsets are later converted to physical addresses during exe file is loaded. At what step exactly the virtual addressing comes ? Is it ike file offsets first convert to VAS and than VAS to Physical address ?

Comment: The file contains code already linked for a particular virtual address. Normally it's loaded there and no more conversion (relocation) is needed but if the information is there, the loader can fix up addresses.

Comment: can you provide some source where i can properly read about it ?

Comment: @LocalHost - Google "exe PE reallocation"